# Swift: Missing Argument for Parameter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

1) I'm using a variable as the first argument in `UIView.animateWithDuration` like so:

```
var theDelay: Float = 1.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration( theDelay, animations: {
    cell.frame.origin.y = 0
})
```

and Xcode6 (Beta 3) is giving me a build error: 'Missing argument for parameter 'delay' in call'.

When I don't use a variable, the function works just fine. I'd like to tweak the variable (as this code is within a loop) when I discovered this issue.

2) Alternatively, I could skip using a variable and include the calculation in-line:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration( indexPath.row * 1.0, animations: {
    cell.frame.origin.y = 0
})
```

but I am getting the same error 'Missing argument for parameter 'delay' in call'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The first parameter  of `animateWithDuration()`
has the type `NSTimeInterval` (which is a `Double`), but you pass a `Float` argument.
Swift does not implicitly convert types.

Changing the variable definition to

```
let theDelay = 1.0
```

or an explicit conversion

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(indexPath.row), animations: {
    cell.frame.origin.y = 0
})
```

should solve the problem.

In **Swift 3** this would be

```
let theDelay = TimeInterval(indexPath.row)
UIView.animate(withDuration: theDelay, animations: {
    cell.frame.origin.y = 0
})
```

Comment: I'm getting this error again in new parts of my code in XCode 6 Beta 5. With or without an explicit Double or NSTimeInterval parameter.

Comment: Hmmm. I fixed it by an explicit addition of UIKit to the library list in Build Phases.

Comment: Alright, it could have been that I was assigning a CGFloat to NSLayoutConstraint instead of NSLayoutConstraint.constant in the animation block. So, if you have this issue, there may be another issue in your block that swift is not telling you about directly. Once I fixed that as well, this error went away and the code ran.

Comment: I'm passing in an `NSTimeInterval` like we're supposed to, and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous downvoter, who reminded me of updating the code for Swift 3 :)

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error from a totally unrelated error in the animations block; I was already passing in a valid `NSTimeInterval`. It had nothing to do with the `delay` parameter, so the error it was showing me was wrong and had me going in circles for a while.

So make sure you don't have any errors inside the animations block.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(interval, animations: { () -> Void in // compiler will complain about this line missing a parameter
            // some code
            // some code with a syntax error in it, but Xcode won't show the error
            // some code
        })
```

Comment: Good catch, I had the same problem. Needed to move the code out of the animation block to make the compiler show the actual problem. Goddamnit!

Answer (score 1):

Actually Swift is typed language and it need to pass same type arguments as defined
**There is no implicit cast in swift.**

As  `animateWithDuration`in decleration

```
class func animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, animations: (() -> Void)!) // delay = 0.0, options = 0, completion = NULL
```

has parameter type of `NSTimeInterval` which is declared as `double` if you see its declaration

```
typealias NSTimeInterval = Double
```

So it need `Double` parameter value not `Float` value.
When you call second timeas in your code than swift is using type interfrence i.e it is automatically defining(not convertting float to double) your `indexPath.row * 1.0` to `Double`.The below code works fine.

```
var theDelay: NSTimeInterval = 1.0
```

or

```
var theDelay: Double = 1.0  //this is same as above
UIView.animateWithDuration( theDelay, animations: {
    cell.frame.origin.y = 0
})
```

Compiler is misguiding you.So always pass parmeter type same as defined in `Swift`